# SceneKit Animation run automatically

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Hey I make a jumping man animation in blender and I imported it in scene kit.

It works fine but there is a problem as I want to make the man not jump until user touch but this character start jumping automatically when I run my code.

How can I control animation not jump automatically?

I have this code:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

var messiArmtr = SCNNode()
var KickAnimation = CAAnimation()
var BoxingAnimation = CAAnimation()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/messi.dae")!
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
 let messiamtr = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("amtr", recursively: true)!
    KickAnimation = CAAnimation.animationWithSceneNamed("art.scnassets/move.dae")!
    messiamtr.addAnimation(KickAnimation, forKey: "amtr")
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not really automatic, you asked it to be played when you added it:

```
messiamtr.addAnimation(KickAnimation, forKey: "amtr")
```